# Oscurart Tools 2.91

Tags: add-on

Looks like the Oscurart Tools have been removed from 2.91. Can anyone confirm? I didn't see anything in the release notes about this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by add-on author Oscurart that the tools were not included. They can be copied over from earlier 2.8+ installs or gotten from his repo.

https://github.com/oscurart/BlenderAddons

Link to answered forum post on BlenderArtists
https://blenderartists.org/t/oscurart-tools-not-included-in-2-91/1267891

Daf